# Python submodule importing correctly in python 3.7 but not 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a directory structure as follows:

```
test/
  __init__.py
  m1/
    __init__.py
    f1.py
    f2.py
```

`test/__init__.py` is empty.

`test/m1/__init__.py` contains a single line `import test.m1.f1`.

`test/m1/f1.py` contains a single line `import test.m1.f2 as f2`.

In python 3.7.6, I can do `import test.m1` and everything works as expected. However, in python 3.6.9 when I try this I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/scratch/test/m1/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    import test.m1.f1
  File "/home/scratch/test/m1/f1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import test.m1.f2 as f2
AttributeError: module 'test' has no attribute 'm1'
```

This seems strange, because it does not error on the `import test.m1.f1`, which is the first thing it encounters. It errors on a subsequent `import test.m1.f2 as f2` statement, claiming that `test` has no `m1` submodule.

Comment: Please can you give the contents of `test/__init__.py`, or if it is empty, say so explicitly.

Comment: I can reproduce it with `test/__init__.py` being empty version 3.6.9 fails. version 3.7.4 passes.

replacing `import test.m1.f2 as f2` with `import test.m1.f2` makes it pass.

Comment: If it's any help, it will work under python 3.6 if you change `test/m1/f1.py` to say `from . import f2`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`import test.m1.f2 as f2` tries to access the `m1` attribute of the `test` module object, as part of the process of finding the object to bind to `f2`. The `m1` attribute won't be set until the `test.m1` subpackage finishes initializing, which won't happen until the `__init__.py` for `test.m1` finishes executing.

[On Python 3.7 and up](https://bugs.python.org/issue30024), if the attribute lookup fails, the import falls back to a `sys.modules['test.m1.f2']` lookup to find `test.m1.f2`. This fallback does not exist on 3.6, causing the observed discrepancy.

[A similar fallback](https://bugs.python.org/issue17636) also exists for circular `from` imports on Python 3.5 and up, though `from . import f2` or `from test.m1 import f2` wouldn't need the fallback. The `from` import retrieves `test.m1` straight from `sys.modules`, so it only looks for the `f2` attribute, and that attribute is present.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the answer explaining the how, but it explains how you can avoid the error. So useful for the ones wanting to write code that runs under 3.6 or earlier.

Replace

```
import test1.m1.f2 as f2
```

with

```
from test.m1 import f2
```

Or as @alaniwi pointed out

```
from . import f2
```

Comment: This works on Python 3.5 and up, but not prior versions.

Comment: For me that works with following versions 2.6.9 2.7.15 3.4.5 3.5.4 3.6.9 3.7.4 3.8.1 or in other words I didn't find any version where it doesn't work, but of course I didn't try all versions. Perhaps you mean 2.5 and higher versions?

Comment: Is that better or worse than using a relative import (`from . import f2`)? (And why?)

Comment: Oh, whoops, you're right. I was thinking of a slightly different case. This import doesn't need the fallback introduced in 3.5, since `f1` and `f2` don't both try to import each other.

Comment: Ah I see.  Circular imports are another painful scenario. this one is just about when the name spaces are populated.

Comment: @alaniwi This might give you opinionated answers.

Explicit relative imports didn't exist in python2 and some coding style checkers issue warnings for relative imports (at least a few years ago pylint did this if I recall correctly) 

I think both are fine.

Comment: Explicit relative imports work fine in Python 2. Python 2's problem is *implicit* relative imports.

Comment: You're right. I mixed it up. With python2 you even get implicit relative imports where you probably wanted an absolute import (except you add `from __future__ import absolute_imports`)